# Making forum using php javascript html and xml

Tags: php, javascript, html, forum

I need to make a forum as part of my project...So which is better ,saving each post and related content in database...or saving topic title and link to topic in database...and storing the topic and related comments in a separate directory as xml files....Please provide me if any other alternate ways are available.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store everything in the database.
That is what databases are for.